# Is there a generic term for measures of correctness like "precision" and "recall"?

Tags: machine-learning, predictive-models, terminology

Suppose I am building some predictive models and then creating a report detailing how "good" those models were in various ways.  Is there a generic (maybe even non-technical) term for the various measures of correctness (e.g. precision, recall, etc.)?  A layman might use "accuracy," but accuracy actually has a very specific meaning and is a subset of possible measures to be included in such a report.  In describing the contents of such a report, should I just use "accuracy" even though there will be other measures of correctness included in such a report?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know if there is a generally accepted generic term, but I think you might say "classifier performance metrics/measures" (like in the `R` package `ROCR`), or "measures of predictive/classification performance".

The widely cited paper by [Fawcett](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.98.4088&rep=rep1&type=pdf), for example, talks about "common performance metrics" and lists true positive rate (tpr), fpr, sensitivity, speficitiy, precision, and recall.

Comment: Yeah, "performance" is probably the best term for that.

Answer (score -2):

I would use precision and recall but explain it with a dart board analogy if necessary.

Comment: I'm doing more than just precision and recall; those two metrics were just cited as examples of whatever it is I'm talking about.